# How to Limit SQL server user to Fetch X limit of rows only

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table in SQL database with 80,000 records, but for security purposes, I would like to grant access to users on can `select` records up to 5,000. 
Any solution?

```
    Select * from Emp
```

Should return only 5,000

Comment: select top 5000 * from Emp

Comment: Use TOP (and optional OFSET)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to grant access to users on can select records up to 5,000. Any solution?

If you are using SQL 2016 or higher, you can achieve this via [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL2016 but no option to limit the number of rows when granting the access ,

Comment: @user3703182, It cannot apply RLS simply with `grant`, when your requirement is to show 5,000 records out of 80,000 per a user, based on which logic (column) the 5,000 records get filtered, is it by _Department, Entity, Country, Location etc.._ , update your question with those details so that i can provide my answer with "how RLS can be applied in your database"

Answer (score 0):

There are `80000` rows as you said and you want to grant access to only `5000` rows, so first you need to decide from 80000 which of the 5000 rows you want to show.

First order them from your record by apply `order by` clause.

After that you may apply `offset` to limit the access of records.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP 
ORDER BY [YOUR ORDER]
OFFSET 0 ROWS            ---- HERE YOU CAN LIMIT FROM WHICH ROW NUMBER YOU WANT TO SHOW NEXT RECORDS TO THE USER.
FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS
```

You can also make procedures to limit the accessibility like this.

```
DECLARE @StartingRowNumber tinyint = 1  
      , @FetchRows tinyint = 8;  
SELECT DepartmentID, Name, GroupName  
FROM HumanResources.Department  
ORDER BY DepartmentID ASC   
    OFFSET @StartingRowNumber ROWS   
    FETCH NEXT @FetchRows ROWS ONLY;
```

For more info on Offset you may find this link .[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

you can put your select `select top 5000 * from Emp` into view , function or sp and manage user permission to use that 
[Grant Permissions on a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) or [GRANT Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, It is better to create a `view` which limits the number of rows to 5000 and then grant select on the view to the users .